# submit new version during developer hold - is that possible?

Tags: app-store-connect, appstore-approval

I submitted the first version of my new app to Apple, it got approved but the release date is currently set to December 2014, because there's some work on the backend to do. I don't know how long it will take to get the work finished, so I'm thinking about submitted an update to the iOS app because I found some little bugs.

If the work on the backend is finished, I would like to go live ASAP. Therefore I don't want to developer reject the version waiting for release; is it possible to keep it in "developer hold" and submit an update or do I first have to release v1.0?

Comment: similar situation - did you ever figure out the answer to this ?

Comment: no, unfortunately not.